# Unresolved Import on Kivy

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy, kivy-language

**Code:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

**Testcode from kivy.org, it works fine when I run the code but I am unresolved import issues on kivy.**

Issues:
`unresolved import 'kivy.app'`
`unresolved import 'kivy.uix.button'`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "it works fine when I run the code" but "I am unresolved import issues on kivy" - does it work or not?

Comment: it works when I run it, but the unresolved import issue is annoying. I also cant lint when that issue is present

Comment: If you can run it, the import can be resolved, so the problem relates to the tool that is telling you otherwise. If you want help fixing it, give all the detail possible about what that tool is and how it is configured.

Comment: @RavenKape -How are things going?  Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, I reproduced the problem you described:

[image]

Solution:

1.You could try to use the Python language service provided by "Jedi": please use `"python.languageServer": "Jedi"` in "`settings.json`".

2.Or when the code can run successfully, we can add the following settings in "`settings.json`" to turn off "unresolved-import":

```
"python.analysis.disabled": [ "unresolved-import" ],
```

[image]